# Concerns about complex valued function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In a textbook Im reading they write the following:

> Let $h,\hat h:D \rightarrow G\subset \mathbb{D}$ (unit disk) two conformal functions. If there is a point $a \in G$ with $h(a) = \hat h(a)$ and $h'(a) / \hat h'(a) > 0$ then follows $h = \hat h$.

Im concerned about  $h'(a) / \hat h'(a) > 0$

$h'(a) / \hat h'(a)$ should be complex valued and one cant say $h'(a) / \hat h'(a) > 0$. I think what they want to say is $h'(a) / \hat h'(a) \neq 0$.

Or is the derivative of a conformal function always real? This does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when people writes (in the context of complex valued function)

$f(a)>0$ for some $a$ in the domain

it means $f(a) \in \mathbb R$ and $f(a)>0$.

(cf. Uniqueness part of Riemann mapping theorem)

Derivative of conformal function need not be real. $h'(a) / \hat h'(a) > 0$ is just a part of the hypothesis of your statement.

Comment: Interesting. The riemann mapping theorem is part of my textbook and is formulated as:

Is $\mathbb{C} \neq D \subset \mathbb{C}$ simply connected, then there is a unique conformal mapping from $D$ onto $\mathbb{D}$ with $f(z_0) = 0$ and $f'(z_0) > 0$.

So does this mean $f'(z_0)$ is always real? How can they assume that?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that $f'(z_0)$ is always real. Theorem just says that there always exist 'UNIQUE' function satisfying positivity condition. If you don't assume positivity condition then you cannot get uniqueness